# select element on checkbox select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show hide an select element on on/off of a checkbox. But its not working.

On page load I want the select to be hidden and on checking the checkbox I want it to be visible.

The code is

```
<input type="checkbox" id="inputBasicOff"  checked />
<select  id="fieldSelect" data-placeholder="Choose Field"> 
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>

</select>
```

And the JS is

```
(function(document, window, $) {
  'use strict';
  var Site = window.Site;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Site.run();
     $('#fieldSelect').hide();
$("#inputBasicOff").change(function() {
if(this.checked) {

      $('#fieldSelect').fadeIn();
}
else{

 $('#fieldSelect').hide();
}
}); 


  });

})(document, window, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this way,

```
$("#inputBasicOff").change(function () {
    this.checked ? $("#fieldSelect").fadeIn() : $("#fieldSelect").fadeOut()
});
```

The problem with your code is, you are trying to select the element with attribute (name)selector. Currently there is no name attribute present on that element.

Comment: Or: `$("#fieldSelect").toggle(this.checked);`  but OP was using `fadeIn()`, here there is no animation

Answer (score 0):

Your `hide()` call appears to be on a completely different element. If you select the right element your code should work. That said, you can improve it by using `toggle()`:

```
(function (document, window, $) {
    'use strict';
    var Site = window.Site;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Site.run();
        $('#fieldSelect').hide();
        $("#inputBasicOff").change(function () {
            $('#fieldSelect').toggle(this.checked);
        });
    });
})(document, window, jQuery);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lst0x4ps/)

Note that the fiddle has the references to `Site` commented out - I assume this is a method/property you have defined yourself, as it is not standard.

Answer (score 0):

hi now try to this way

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#inputBasicOff').on('change', function(){
    
    
    $('#fieldSelect').toggle();
  });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="inputBasicOff"  checked />
<select  id="fieldSelect" data-placeholder="Choose Field"> 
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>

</select>
```